# Ruby: How do you read strings that span several lines?

Tags: ruby, gets

Context:

In programming competitions, test cases are often very large. When the problem deals with strings, these given strings could be made up of 10^5 characters or more.

please see this judge input:
https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/april-easy-challenge-15/problems/battle-of-words/af078bfa-d-input-af07897.txt?Signature=qlPyGqHaNOSmMOUhFTiNjn83hnk%3D&Expires=1432444347&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:
https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/battle-of-words/

And here is my solution in RUBY which passed only 3 of the 10 given test cases:

```
swapflag = 0
n = gets.to_i
for i in 0..n-1
    tc = gets
    tc2 = gets
    if tc.length > tc2.length
        tmp = tc2
        tc2 = tc
        tc = tmp
        swapflag = 1
    end

    tc.delete! " "
    tc2.delete! " "

    tc.split("").each do |x|
        if tc2.include? x
            #print x
            tc = tc.sub(x,'')
            tc2 = tc2.sub(x,'')
        end
    end
    #puts tc, tc2
    if tc.length > 0 and tc2.length == 0 and swapflag == 0
        puts "You win some."
    elsif tc.length > 0 and tc2.length == 0 and swapflag == 1
        puts "You lose some."
    elsif tc.length == 0 and tc2.length > 0 and swapflag == 0
        puts "You lose some."
    elsif tc.length == 0 and tc2.length > 0 and swapflag == 1
        puts "You win some."
    else
        puts "You draw some."
    end

    swapflag = 0
end
```

Upon checking, it appears that the gets function I use to read the lines of input fail to read strings when the string gets to large and span several lines.

Is there a way to tell ruby to read strings spanning several lines?

Thanks in advance.

*I cannot post images yet, reputation less than 10*

Answer (score 0):

`gets` can read an input line with maximum length of that problem just fine (in there !). From what I know, the number of characters you can read with `gets` is only limited by the amount of memory available for your code and they provide enough.

In the input you linked, there are actually 10*2 = 15 lines after first line. It's just that in the browser, the lengthy lines are wrapped up, making it look like they are split into more than 1 line. So using two `gets` is enough to read two lines of a test case.

So you are reading lines just fine, you will have to check the parts that come after reading them.